# Не работает dns

Tags: ubuntu

Установил на второй компьютер ubuntu server 14.04. Всё настроил, установил ngnix, настроил так, что бы запрос был на имя сайта sn.net, при попытке подключиться в локальной сети по sn.net пишет, что такого сайта нету, но при попытке подключится по ip адресу самого сервера 192.168.2.219 он перенаправляет на sn.net. Почему не получается подключиться выводит нет такого сайта, и как сделать так, что бы в локальной сети можно было подключится? Роутер у меня от ASUS RT-N12.

Comment: Судя по всему, домен sn.net куплен не вами, так что использовать его наверно бессмысленно

Answer (score 0):

Есть 2 способа:

1. Сложный. Нужно установить собственный DNS сервер, в котором описать зоны, по которым sn.net будет резолвится в ваш IP 192.168.2.219

   Пример установки и настройки, для CentOS можно найти вот здесь:
   https://habrahabr.ru/post/245857/
2. Простой. Нужно на каждом клиенте добавить в `/etc/hosts` следующую запись:

   `192.168.2.219   sn.net`

В таком случае, в соответствии с настройкой `/etc/nsswitch.conf` при запросе этого адреса, сначала резолвер попытается найти соответствие в нашем, измененном, файле, а уж затем - пойдет в DNS

Comment: 3. Правильный — купить домен :)

Comment: Не очень хочется кому то деньге за домен отдавать.

Comment: @andreymal не, данный способ не является решением поставленной задачи. ему, считай, нужен маленький интранет.